# Converting Time-Stamp String to Another Date Format in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have datetime stamp (`MMDDYYYYHHMMSS`) extracted from a file  Name as

```
Filedate = "10212015140108"
```

How can I convert it into datetime format `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`.

Can someone help to get it resolved?

Comment: So you have an existing VBScript and it has a variable called Filedate  which contains 10212015140108 ? Post your code and also explain the rules on how this number could be converted.

Comment: Ideally you should post your workings so far, if you expect to be helped.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I think the format is fairly obvious if you look at it close enough - `mmddyyyyhhnnss` *(21 Oct 2015 14:01:08)*

Comment: To someone from Australia it's not immediately obvious (our data format is d - m - y). To expedite an answer its in your interests to specify these things straight up. PS you still haven't posted your code.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I'm from the UK but have worked with various date formats for years. OP should still be posting some code to show the context of the question.

Comment: Yes its in the OP's interests that we don't read his mind. Question effort made: none

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I've broke the cardinal rule by answering it *(don't shoot me)* just happened to interest me whether I could write a 2 minute script to parse it. Admittedly though I don't want to encourage this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather from the question it looks as though the `Filedate` value is just a string representation of date *(`mmddyyyyhhnnss`)*, with that in mind did a quick test to see if I could parse it into the format required.

There are other ways of approaching this like using a `RegExp` object to build up a list of matches then use those to build the output.

> Worth noting that this example will only work if the structured string is always in the same order and the same number of characters.

```
Function ParseTimeStamp(ts)
    Dim df(5), bk, ds, i

    'Holds the map to show how the string breaks down, each element
    'is the length of the given part of the timestamp.
    bk = Array(2,2,4,2,2,2)
    pos = 1
    For i = 0 To UBound(bk)
        df(i) = Mid(ts, pos, bk(i))
        pos = pos + bk(i)
    Next
    'Once we have all the parts stitch them back together.
    'Use the mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss format
    ds = df(0) & "/" & df(1) & "/" & df(2) & " " & df(3) & ":" & df(4) & ":" & df(5)
    ParseTimeStamp = ds
End Function

Dim Filedate, parsedDate

Filedate = "10212015140108" 
parsedDate = ParseTimeStamp(FileDate)
WScript.Echo parsedDate
```

Output:

```
10/21/2015 14:01:08
```