# Sqlite column is formatted as timestamp and when accessed via asp classic, value is returned as null

Tags: sqlite, asp-classic

I have uploaded a sqlite database onto my server.  The database simply contains two fields, one being the ID and the other being a date that is defined as timestamp (looks as if it's a unix date).

After opening the database, using classic asp, my code is written to display the data from the records.  However, the date field is displayed as null when accessed via code.  I have not seen this behavior before so I'm missing something simple.  There are other fields in the database which I can easily get access to, but any field that is typed as timestamp is not able to be accessed and manipulated into a proper human date.

Below is the simple version of code.  What do I need to do to access the date?  This should be a very simple thing to do but I am obviously missing something here.  In all the years of programming, I don't think I've ever had to use someone else's database who has defined a field as timestamp.  I never use that type.

Hopefully this is a simple problem.  Thanks so much...

```
dim hotAirOconn

set hotAirOconn=server.createobject ("ADODB.connection")

hotAirOconn.open "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=C:/lindsey/webPages/azAirVentures/database/textfiles_AZAirVentures/hotAir/hotAirDatabase_"&request("commandID")&".sqlite;LongNames=0;Timeout=1000;NoTXN=0;SyncPragma=NORMAL;StepAPI=0;    "

set db = server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

query="select * from zFlight"

db.Open query, hotAirOconn, adopenkeyset

while not db.eof

response.write db("zDateofFlight")

db.movenext

wend
```

Comment: can you try changing your query from `select * from zFlight` to `select ID, myDateColumn from zFlight` ? -- edit: I may have misunderstood what you are asking, and if you just need to convert the timestamp to a date, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33279052/converting-time-stamp-string-to-another-date-format-in-vbscript

Comment: I understand your query change, but that has been tried knowing that it wouldn't really change anything.  If I could read the data, I have no problem converting it to a date from a timestamp.  Issue is when I fetch the timestamp from the database and try and read it, it returns null.  There is nothing there.  If I try another field, say an integer field, I can read it no problem.  But nothing is returned into my software from a timestamp.  So any conversions once I have the timestamp value just errors out because I'm trying to convert it from a null string.  Thanks....

Comment: What is returned in the query when you run it directly against the database using a tool like SQLite browser? Do you see the timestamp values or null?

Comment: When I run the query, select zDateOfFlight from zFlight, it does return the results of the timestamp.  But when I run classic asp code with the same query, the results come back as null.  If I use sqllite studio, I can actually change the timestamp field to a string and I can read it perfectly in my code.  But I just don't want to do it that way.  I basically upload a new database once a week and don't want to go to the server and change the field type.  I've also tried to execute a sql command, within the asp code, to change the field to a string but haven't been successful in that method.

Comment: Have you already tried to CAST the column as a DATE? `SELECT DATE(zDateOfFlight) AS zDateOfFlight FROM zFlight`

Comment: When I use the above query, the results returned are still null.  As I said before, I can manually change the field zDateOfFlight to a string and it works fine.  Can I use something like "Select String(zDateOfFlight) as zDateOfFlight from ZFlight"?  I tried, but it doesn't like String.  I'm researching now.  Maybe it's not possible.  Queries I write are very simple and straight forward.  Not exactly sure how to convert it to a string during the query process.  Thanks.

Comment: So I finally got some results using the query " select strftime('%d-%m-%Y', datetime(zDateOfFlight, 'unixepoch')) as_string"  It actually returned results that I can manipulate.  Not sure if this is the best way but it does work.  If anyone else has a better thought, let me know.  Thanks.